# WordPress function undefined: file_is_displayable_image()

Tags: image, wordpress, function, undefined

When I call the function file_is_displayable_image() from my template file, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_is_displayable_image()

The function works fine when I call using a hook, but I'm not sure why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never do anything in a theme before the hook `after_setup_theme`. Wait until all needed functions [are available](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/14042/73).